# Using MySQL Common Table Expressions to solve the travelling salesman problem

Tags: algorithms, graphs, sql

The problem I'm trying to solve is very similar to the [travelling salesman problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem), where there are many paths between nodes in the database. I've tried to edit my example to fit into this well-known problem (the actual database is connections between molecules in a medical context).

I have a simple database with two tables: `node` and `node_parent`. Within `node` is a primary key `id` and other metadata about the node, but I'm only interested in the parent:child relationships, so I'll only be interrogating the `node_parent` table.

There are only two fields within `node_parent`, `nodeId` and `nodeParentId`, both foreign keys to the `node` table.

The end goal is to be able to enter two node IDs, and be provided with the different paths that could be taken to connect them together, not just the shortest route.

What I've tried so far is to use a recursive query using [Common Table Expressions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html) to build up a string showing the path.

Here's the database schema:

```sql
create table `node` (
  `id` varchar(32) not null,
  `name` varchar(512) not null,

  primary key (`id`),
  key(`name`)
);

create table `node_parent` (
  `nodeId` varchar(32) not null,
  `parentNodeId` varchar(32) not null,

  primary key(`nodeId`, `parentNodeId`),
  constraint `node_parent_node`
    foreign key (`nodeId`) references `node`(`id`) 
    on update cascade on delete cascade,
  constraint `node_parent_parentNode`
    foreign key (`parentNodeId`) references `node`(`id`) 
    on update cascade on delete cascade
);
```

and here's my attempt at using a CTE for this kind of thing, with the `concat()` function being used to build up a string that shows each node in the relationship and whether it's a parent or child relationship by using `>(p)>` or `>(c)>`:

```sql
with recursive cte (nodeId, parentNodeId, n, path) as (
    select
        p.nodeId,
        p.parentNodeId,
        1,
        concat(p.nodeId, '>(p)>', p.parentNodeId)
    from
        node_parent p

-- this is the starting node's ID
    where
        p.nodeId = 'example123'

-- there must be a union to a recursive call for this to work
    union all

    select
        p2.nodeId,
        p2.parentNodeId,
        cte.n + 1,
        concat( path, '>(p)>', p2.nodeId)
    from
        node_parent p2

    inner join cte on p2.nodeId = cte.parentNodeId

    where cte.n < 3

-- here I'm using another union to check for child relationships,
-- but I suspect my logic is incorrect here...
    union all

    select
        p2.nodeId,
        p2.parentNodeId,
        cte.n + 1,
        concat( path, '>(c)>', p2.nodeId)
    from
        node_parent p2

    inner join cte on p2.parentNodeId = cte.nodeId

-- I'm limiting the depth of the search to 3, but ideally I'd want at least 5
-- steps.
    where cte.n < 3
)
select distinct nodeId, parentNodeId, path from cte
```

Maybe my attempt at SQL is simply incorrect, or maybe I'm going about solving the problem from a completely wrong approach. So I'm asking here for any feedback from data scientists that might be able to make my life a bit easier. Thanks!

Comment: Setting it up as parent/child like this implies a tree relationship, is that really what you need for modeling connections between molecules? What's going to happen when you have rings, etc.? Wouldn't you just want a table of vertices?

Comment: @C8H10N4O2 you are exactly right. I just needed to sleep on it, and now the problem seems so much more simple. I _do_ care about the direction of the relationship, but that can be stored as metadata on the relationship table. Two vertices, two nodes, two directions.